# WordPress Author page not pulling data

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to start by saying this could be an entirely amateur question. If it is, I apologize.

I have a blog running at http://downinthep.it/. We have authors set to show on http://downinthep.it/about/

When you click on the first author (Ryan) everything shows just fine. If you click on any of the others, it displays the first author's (Ryan) bio and information, but it shows the correct link and title attribute.

Is there something wrong with the loop integration? Here's my author.php:

```
    <?php
        get_header();
        if ( $post == NULL ) {
            $cb_author_id = $author;
        } else {
            $cb_author_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
        }

    $cb_author_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $cb_author_id );
        $cb_theme_style = ot_get_option( 'cb_theme_style', 'cb_boxed' );
?>
<div class="cb-cat-header<?php if ( $cb_theme_style == 'cb_boxed' ) echo ' wrap'; ?>">

        <h1 id="cb-cat-title"><span><?php echo __( 'Author', 'cubell' ) . ' <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></span> ' . $cb_author_name; ?></h1>

</div>

<div id="cb-content" class="cb-author-page wrap clearfix">

    <?php echo cb_author_details( $cb_author_id ); ?>

    <div id="main" class="clearfix" role="main">

        <?php get_template_part( 'cat', 'style-a' ); ?>

    </div> <!-- end #main -->

</div> <!-- end #cb-content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Does anything stand out to you? What am I missing?

Comment: use a different page template for each author id look on the wordpress codex [wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates)

Comment: @TheWebMann While I can do that, is that the solution to this problem, or is it just a fix?

Comment: well I can not see where you are setting the variable $author but if you use author-'author-name.php it should fix your problems